# Mysql same DB, same query, different users - different error messages

Tags: mysql, errors, mysql-8.0

On my AWS RDS Mysql 8.0.16 server I have one DB (`my-db`) and 2 users: the `master` user (created automatically by RDS) and an app user created by me:

```
create user if not exists `appuser`@`%` identified by 's3cr3t';
grant all on `my-db`.* to `appuser`@`%`;
```

When I run the `delete from Things where id = 123` query on behalf of the `appuser`, the error message I get is:

> [23000][1217] Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

(**1217** and no constraint details)

When I run *the same query* as a master user, the error message is:

> [23000][1451] Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`my-db`.`Sandwiches`, CONSTRAINT `SandwichesThingIdFK` FOREIGN KEY (`thingId`) REFERENCES `Things` (`id`))

(**1451** and there are constraint details)

How do I make `appuser` get 1451 and all the details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this issue is specific to Mysql 8.0.16. I've upgraded to 8.0.21 and I now get 1451 as expected.

Longer answer: 1217 (`ER_ROW_IS_REFERENCED`) and 1451 (`ER_ROW_IS_REFERENCED_2`) both describe the same situation. As far as I understand, Mysql will use 1451 if user has a [`REFERENCES` privilege](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_references) for the table of interest, and 1217 otherwise. And it's the same story about 1216 (`ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW`) vs 1452 (`ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2`).