# Error 1216, not 1451, despite reference privilege on MySQL 8

Tags: permissions, mysql-8.0

MySQL 8.0.34

Limited-privilege users see less verbose errors (1216/1217) per the [design intent](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=3443). I've granted reference privileges, as suggested [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/282019/284257), in an attempt to show more verbose errors (1451/1452) for all users. But `mybasic` user still sees the less verbose versions.

Difference in user privileges:

```sql
mysql> show grants for 'myadmin';
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for myadmin@%                                         |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `myadmin`@`%`                          |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `%`.* TO `myadmin`@`%`               |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `common\_%`.* TO `myadmin`@`%`       |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+

mysql> show grants for 'mybasic';
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for mybasic@%                                         |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT REFERENCES ON *.* TO `mybasic`@`%`                     |
| GRANT SELECT, REFERENCES ON `%`.* TO `mybasic`@`%`           |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `common\_%`.* TO `mybasic`@`%`       |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I then tried to run the following delete from each account:

```sql
DELETE FROM `common_one`.`one` WHERE ( (`field`="value"));
```

On `myadmin`, the result is as expected. I've followed this trail, and it seems like all dependencies are within the `common` database.

```sql
ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`common_two`.`_two`, CONSTRAINT `_two_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`field`) REFERENCES `common_one`.`one` (`field`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

On `mybasic`, the result is the less verbose version:

```sql
ERROR 1217 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

What changes can I make to the `mybasic` user to see the more verbose errors? Are there settings I can adjust or logs I can use to inspect the problem? The Python interface my team uses, DataJoint, relies on the verbose version to suggest cascading deletes, so this has been a major hurdle for us.

EDIT: `` GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `%`.* TO `mybasic`@`%`; `` leads to the desired error, but reduces security in a way I'd like to avoid